# How to iterate through Hashtable that has values as List?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I wanted to have multiple values for a single key in my hashtable, so I created key value pair as

```
Hashtable A = new Hashtable(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

List<string> DataList = new List<string>();
DataList.Add(userName);
DataList.Add(firstName);
DataList.Add(lastName);
DataList.Add(Pwd);

if (!A.ContainsKey(ID))
{ 
    A.Add(ID, DataList);
}
```

For example, my hashtable contains values as

```
Hashtable A -> Key : 1 , Value : {'A','B','1234','@red'}

Hashtable B -> Key : 2, Value : {'Emma','B','111','@blue'}
```

I have two hashtables and I want to compare the date using the key. If the key is present in both tables, then I wish to compare the values of that key in both tables. If there is any change, then I output it.

For example, if ID- 1001 is present in both A and B, then I check the list of values in both table for `1001`. If for example, A has third value '1234' and B has third value as '111', then I output `111`.

Its just a comparison of hashtable but I am stuck at iterating through the values.

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry details in A)
{
    if(details.Key.Equals(Key of Hashtable B))
    {
        //I want to do something like this if both Hashtables have same key
        string firstname = 'A';
        string lastname = 'B';
        string password ='1234' and so on...
        // I just wish to store the values of first hashtable in some variables so that I can use them further.
    }
}
```

I tried using foreach but it gave me error that

```
Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

How do I parse through this list of values in Hashtable?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]. Through copy pasting or just adding pseudocode it is really unclear what is a mistake and what is a deliberate text. Please separate your best try and the text of what you want to achieve.

Comment: A `Hashtable` is not generic so something like `Hashtable<string, List<String>>` doesnt exist. Maybe you actually mean a `Dictionary<string, List<String>>`. If you really use a `HashTable`, why? There's almost no reason to still use it nowadays

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do from your question. What are your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Also, according to Microsoft's documentation on Hashtables, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-6.0#remarks), it appears that you should be using a Dictionary instead.

Comment: I updated my question . Adding a bit of code of what I did and how I created the hashtable.

Comment: I just want to know a way to iterate through the list that I put in as values.

Comment: @a_naq That's helpful but we need to know what you expect to happen when you run your code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments and your question, I gather you want to iterate over the values and do something with them. The reason you can't is because the `HashTable` is a non-generic collection, so all your values are stored as type `object`, ergo the error. To fix this, you need to type-cast what you receive as a `List<string>`:

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry details in A)
{
    if(B.ContainsKey(details.Key))
    {
        List<string> data = B[details.Key] as List<string>;
        // Do the thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm missing the recommendation to prefer a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

Comment: Agreed. I'll add that later as this is the direct answer to the OP's question